# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm receiving an error whenever I attempt to insert into my database using PDO.

```
public function save($primaryKey = "") {
        $validate = $this->rules();
        if ($validate === true) {
            $properties = '';
            $values = '';
            $bindings = array();
            $update = '';
            foreach ($this as $property => $value){
                if ($property === "conn") {
                    continue;
                }
                $properties .= $property . ',';
                $values .= ':' . $property . ',';
                $update .= $property . ' = :' . $property . ',';
                $bindings[':'.$property] = $value;
            }
            $sql_string = 'INSERT INTO ' . get_class($this) . ' (' . rtrim($properties, ',') . ') ';
            $sql_string .= 'VALUES (' . rtrim($values, ',') . ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' . rtrim($update, ',') . ';';
            $result = $this->executeQuery(NULL, $sql_string, $bindings);
            $this->buildObject($result);
            if (!empty($primaryKey)) {
                $this->$primaryKey = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
            }
            return $result;
        } else {
            return $validate;
        }
    }

public function executeQuery($object, $sql_string, $bindings = null) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql_string);
        if (!empty($bindings)) {
            if (!$stmt->execute($bindings)) {return false;}
        } else {
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {return false;}
        }
        $result = (!empty($object) ? $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $object) : $stmt->fetchAll());
        return (($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? $result : false);
    }
```

The save function generates both the query string and the bindings which both seem correct.

```
query = INSERT INTO am_administrator (firstName,lastName,username,password,email,isSuperUser,dateCreated,dateLastModified) VALUES (:firstName,:lastName,:username,:password,:email,:isSuperUser,:dateCreated,:dateLastModified) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstName = :firstName,lastName = :lastName,username = :username,password = :password,email = :email,isSuperUser = :isSuperUser,dateCreated = :dateCreated,dateLastModified = :dateLastModified;

bindings = array(8) { 
[":firstName"]=> string(5) "First" 
[":lastName"]=> string(4) "Last" 
[":username"]=> string(7) "cova-fl" 
[":password"]=> string(8) "password" 
[":email"]=> string(16) "test@testing.com" 
[":isSuperUser"]=> int(1) "1" 
[":dateCreated"]=> string(19) "2016-05-11 02:40:15" 
[":dateLastModified"]=> string(19) "2016-05-11 02:40:15" 
}
```

Whenever I put the query into workbench I have no problems, but when trying to run it in code I get Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' which confuses me since the number of bindings params matches the bindings keys and nummbers. Can anyone enlighten me on this issue?

Comment: Note: It's usually a lot better to do `$values = [ ]`, then append to that array and finally `implode($values, ',')` than to concatenate and strip off the excess `,`.

Comment: At some point you'll want to consider using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) if not a proper [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) before you end up rolling your own by accident. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is particularly easy to get going with and already does what you need out of the box.

Comment: @tadman Noted, will make that change. Would you happen to know anything about my primary issue? I'm limited on the ORM due to restrictions in place. So I might end up building a tiny one which isn't good or fun...

Comment: Yeah, I feel for you. Using an off-the-shelf one is always a better plan than rolling your own. Takes way less time to learn how to use it than to fumble along and write it from scratch. What you're doing here is intense enough I hope you have unit tests to verify it works correctly.

Comment: Yeah, unit test are the only things that makes this even slightly possible

Comment: Why was the question down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be because you have decared each binding twice in the statement e.g. `:firstname` appears in the `VALUES` clause as well as the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.

You only pass 8 bindings to the `$stmt->execute` but PDO is looking for 16.

You could try naming them slightly different in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause giving you a query such as e.g.

`INSERT INTO am_administrator (firstName,lastName,username,password,email,isSuperUser,dateCreated,dateLastModified) VALUES (:firstName,:lastName,:username,:password,:email,:isSuperUser,:dateCreated,:dateLastModified) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstName = :update_firstName,lastName = :update_lastName,username = :update_username,password = :update_password,email = :update_email,isSuperUser = :update_isSuperUser,dateCreated = :update_dateCreated,dateLastModified = :update_dateLastModified;`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that binding values couldn't be shared across all instances of the binding param in the query string.

Comment: Why not just use [VALUES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) e.g. `INSERT INTO table (firstName, lastName) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstName = VALUES(firstName), lastName = VALUES(lastName)` ? That way you don't need to have so many placeholders.